# Python List Division Having multiple values

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list:

```
[('66.162.222.50', 4), ('88.112.19.251', 4), ('207.241.237.226', 3), ('207.241.237.224', 2), ('207.241.237.103', 2), ('74.125.19.82', 1)]
```

That has the IP address and the count of duplicate IP addresses found in a log: `('IP address', count)`

What would be the easiest way for me to create a new list that would consist of the same IP addresses but would change the count to a percentage of total amount? Meaning that in this example we have a total of 4+4+3+2+2+2 which equals to 16 IP addresses, so the new list should look like this:

```
[('66.162.222.50', 0.25), ('88.112.19.251', 0.25), ('207.241.237.226', 0.1875), ('207.241.237.224', 0.125), ('207.241.237.103', 0.125), ('74.125.19.82', 0.0625)]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts? Providing a [mcve] with code will help us to better understand how to help you

Comment: FYI, that's a fraction, not a percentage. Percentage is the fraction multiplied by 100.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem like so: first sum all counts, to get the total number of IPs, and then iterate through every tuple and add a new one with the percentage (fraction) instead of count.

```py
lst = [('66.162.222.50', 4), ('88.112.19.251', 4), ('207.241.237.226', 3), ('207.241.237.224', 2), ('207.241.237.103', 2), ('74.125.19.82', 1)]

total = sum(i[1] for i in lst)
new_lst = [(i[0], i[1]/total) for i in lst]
print(new_lst) # output: [('66.162.222.50', 0.25), ('88.112.19.251', 0.25), ('207.241.237.226', 0.1875), ('207.241.237.224', 0.125), ('207.241.237.103', 0.125), ('74.125.19.82', 0.0625)]
```

Comment: I think it's more pythonic to use a list comprehension for the second part.

Comment: Correct, updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some list comprehension here to sum the total and then calculate the percentage like so:

```
#dummy data
x = [('1',2),('2',3),('3',4)]

#calculate the total
total = sum([a[1] for a in x])

#calculate percentages
y = [(a[0], a[1]/total) for a in x]
```

where x is your input and y would be your output